# Having trouble with programming ESP8266-01 chips. Connection Issue?

Tags: esp8266, firmware, flashing, esptool

I'm trying to program these ESP chips but in order to upload to them, I need something called '**esptool.py**' and flash the firmware on each chip in order to do so. I have got to a point where I have the chip connected and I am giving the prompt this command

> "esptool.py --port COM6 --baud 74880 --trace --before no_reset
>   erase_flash"

. In total, it comes out with this error:

> "A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to Espressif device:
>   Invalid head of packet (0x08)"

I have researched this problem, and they have said that there must be something wrong with the USB interface that I am using. I don't this is the case because as it is uploading the BLUE LED is lighting up in synchronization with the command line.

```
esptool.py --port COM6 --baud 74880 --trace --before no_reset erase_flash
esptool.py v2.7
Serial port COM6
Connecting...TRACE +0.000 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.012 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9898521581051581 0515810535830d15 | ..R.........5...
    832d158b0515ab05 158105           | .-.........
.TRACE +0.053 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.002 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.012 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9a9a52158b0515ab 0515810515810515 | ..R.............
    810515810515830d 15830d           | ...........
.TRACE +0.052 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.000 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9898521581051581 0535830d15832d15 | ..R......5....-.
    8b05158105158105 158105           | ...........
.TRACE +0.052 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.000 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9a9a52158b05158b 0515810515810515 | ..R.............
    810515810515810d 15830d           | ...........
.TRACE +0.052 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.012 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9898521581051581 0d15830d158b0515 | ..R.............
    8b05158105158105 158105           | ...........
.TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9898521581053583 0d15832d158b0515 | ..R...5....-....
    ab05158105158105 158105           | ...........
_TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    98985215810d1583 0d158b05158b0515 | ..R.............
    8105158105158105 158105           | ...........
_TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    929a521581051581 0515810515810515 | ..R.............
    810515830d15830d 158b05           | ...........
_TRACE +0.052 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9898521581051581 0d15830d158b0515 | ..R.............
    8b05158105158105 158105           | ...........
_TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.002 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.000 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9a9a52158b0515ab 0515810515810515 | ..R.............
    810515810515830d 15830d           | ...........
_TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    929a521581051581 0515810515810515 | ..R.............
    810535830d15832d 158b05           | ..5....-...
.TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9898521581051581 0515810515830d15 | ..R.............
    8305158b05158105 158105           | ...........
.TRACE +0.052 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.000 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    98985215830d158b 05158b0515810515 | ..R.............
    8105158105158105 15810d           | ...........
.TRACE +0.053 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.000 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9898521581051581 0d15830d158b0515 | ..R.............
    8b05158105158105 158105           | ...........
.TRACE +0.053 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9a9a52158b0515ab 0515810515810515 | ..R.............
    810515810515810d 15830d           | ...........
.TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.002 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    98985215830d158b 05158b0515810515 | ..R.............
    8105158105158105 158105           | ...........
_TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9898521581051581 0515810515830d15 | ..R.............
    8305158b05158105 158105           | ...........
_TRACE +0.052 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.002 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.012 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    929a521581051581 0515810515810515 | ..R.............
    810515830d15830d 158b05           | ...........
_TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9898521581051581 0515810d15830d15 | ..R.............
    8b05158b05158105 158105           | ...........
_TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.002 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    98985215830d1583 0d158b05158b0515 | ..R.............
    8105158105158105 158105           | ...........
_TRACE +0.052 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9a9a52158b0515ab 0515810515810515 | ..R.............
    810515810515830d 15830d           | ...........
.TRACE +0.051 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.002 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    98985215810d1583 0d158b05158b0515 | ..R.............
    8105158105158105 158105           | ...........
.TRACE +0.052 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.000 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9898521581051581 0515810d15830d15 | ..R.............
    8b05158b05158105 158105           | ...........
.TRACE +0.052 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.012 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.001 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    9898521581051581 0d15830d158b0515 | ..R.............
    8b05158105158105 158105           | ...........
.TRACE +0.052 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.001 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.
TRACE +0.013 Read 1 bytes: 08
TRACE +0.000 Read invalid data: 08
TRACE +0.000 Remaining data in serial buffer:
    929a52158b051581 0515810515810515 | ..R.............
    810515810d15830d 158b05           | ...........
.TRACE +0.052 command op=0x08 data len=36 wait_response=1 timeout=0.100 data=
    0707122055555555 5555555555555555 | ... UUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    55555555                          | UUUU
TRACE +0.000 Write 46 bytes:
    c000082400000000 0007071220555555 | ...$........ UUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555555555 | UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
    5555555555555555 5555555555c0     | UUUUUUUUUUUUU.

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to Espressif device: Invalid head of packet (0x08)
```

I was expecting it to connect to the chip and erase the flash drive or something, but there is obviously a connection issue.

Here is a link to my other forum: [Link](https://github.community/t5/Project-Development-Help-and/Having-trouble-with-programming-ESP8266-01-chips-Trying-to-flash/m-p/27947#M4169)

Comment: Have you verified the baud rate? Try 115200. See http://forum.espruino.com/conversations/300159/

Comment: Yeah i have tried changing the baud rate. I've tried slower ones too like 9600. When i do this however it comes out with "A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to Espressif device: Timed out waiting for packet header"

Comment: Did you try 115200? The baud rate must match or be very close(async) to the expected value otherwise communication is impossible since it is garbled. The baud rate of 74880 is non-standard(IMO), and may not be supported by your `UART` or driver.

Comment: I have tried 9600,74880 and 115200. 74880 Is the only one that identifies a 'head of packet (0x08)' whatever that means. I used 74880 because its apparently the baud rate for the boot loader.